# 'IF" Formula in Excel with additional conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am working on a template which calculates the cost/price of a cabinet and I'm stuck at a certain point. There are 3 types of cabinets and there is a condition where a particular cost is applied to the cabinet type based on its size (Height, Width and Depth)

The condition is: 
For TALL CABINETS- 84 Inch HIGH, 24 Inch DEEP, Cost is $90 PER LINEAR FT.

1. add $1.00 in cost for every additional inch in height
2. add $1.00 in cost for every additional inch in depth or subtract $1.00 for every inch under 24 inch depth

For WALL CABINETS- 13 Inch DEEP and 30 Inch OR LESS IN HEIGHT, cost is $30 PER LINEAR FT.

1. add $.50 for every additional inch in height
2. add $.50 for every additional inch in depth

For BASE CABINETS- 24 Inch DEEP and 34 ½ Inch HIGH, Cost is $40 PER LINEAR FT.

1. add $.50 for every additional inch in depth
2. subtract $.50 for every inch under 24 inch in depth
3. add or subtract $.50 for every inch above or below 34 ½ inch high

Right now I have an `IF` formula for calculating the standard cost as per standard size of the all the three cabinet types (See below and attached file). But I want to change/modify the formula to show the change in cost when the Size changes.

```
=IF($C$5="Base Cabinet",($O$3*$C$6*$F$6),IF($C$5="Wall Cabinet",($O$4*$C$6*$F$6),IF($C$5="Tall Cabinet",($O$5*$C$6*$F$6),"Type not listed")))
```

So for example with above formula if I select a Base Cabinet the cost will show $80, but the size is not considered here as of now. Let's say if the size of the Cabinet is 34.5 (High) x 24 (Deep), then the value I am getting ($80) is correct, but if the size increases or decreases, the value should change. So this is what I need help with.

The example file is on below location:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/278ofqek96uj3e3/AAA_XCEoqQxqOWIh3ZeRtIAra?dl=0

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question, what might be complicating the problem for you is thinking of the adjustments you want to add as additional "conditions" (if a cabinet dimension varies from the standard, then adjust).  Actually, they aren't conditions, just calculations that can be incorporated into your formula.  For standard dimensions, the adjustments equal zero.

You already have the framework there.  All you need to do is add the additional calculations.  I'm assuming that your cost adjustments are to the cost per LF, not net to the price of the cabinet.

Right now, you have a "base" cost per LF in column O, to which you want to add adjustments.  You describe two types of adjustments:

- "add or subtract", which would be in the form of (actual - standard) * adjustment
- "add if greater", which would be in the form of (MAX(actual, standard) - standard) * adjustment

If there is any chance that the adjustment value might change over time, it is good practice to store those in a cell, say in column P (or P and Q), associated with the cabinet type, and refer to the cell in the formula rather than hard-code the value.  That will save having to modify your formulas later.  For this example, though, I will just include the value in the formula.  So adding the adjustments would look like this:

```
=IF($C$5="Base Cabinet",(($O$3+($F$3-34.5)*0.5+($F$5-24)*0.5)*$C$6*$F$6),
 IF($C$5="Wall Cabinet",(($O$4+(MAX($F$3,30)-30)*0.5+(MAX($F$5,13)-13)*0.5)*$C$6*$F$6),
 IF($C$5="Tall Cabinet",(($O$5+($F$3-84)*1+(MAX($F$5,24)-24)*1)*$C$6*$F$6),"Type not listed")))
```

Note that I split the formula to multiple lines for readability.  If you want to copy and paste, delete the carriage returns and extra spaces first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful. I just made a small change in your formula. For Base and Wall Cabinets, instead of multiplying by 0.5 I multiplied by 0.25 so that I get the correct results. So I used this =IF($C$5="Base Cabinet",(($O$3+($F$3-34.5)*0.25+($F$5-24)*0.25)*$C$6*$F$6), IF($C$5="Wall Cabinet",(($O$4+(MAX($F$3,30)-30)*0.25+(MAX($F$5,13)-13)*0.25)*$C$6*$F$6), IF($C$5="Tall Cabinet",(($O$5+($F$3-84)*1+(MAX($F$5,24)-24)*1)*$C$6*$F$6),"Type not listed")))

Comment: That's why I suggested doing the adjustment amount (0.5 vs. 0.25), as a stored value that you reference in the formula.  Over time, with inflation and all, costs will change.  That way, they're visible variables that are easy to maintain.  This was an interesting question.